# Expectation of a random variable and the indicator random variable proof

Tags: probability, self-study, proof, mathematical-statistics

I need to show that $E[T 1_A] = E[T|A]P(A)$.

What I've got so far is $E[T1_A] = \int_{\Omega}T.1_A dP = \int_AT dP$.

Now I know that $\int_AdP = P(A)$ however I'm lost as to how do I get the conditional probability?

Edit: Forgot to mention that T is a $Z_+$ random variable

Comment: Oftentimes the first relationship you have written is taken as the definition of $E[X \mid A]$. What conditional expectations have you defined?

Comment: If this is a homework question, you should use the homework tag. That way, people will know to give you a hint and not the full answer.

Comment: Hint: Multiply and divide by $P(A)$ the integral you have arrived at.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, it is common to define 
$$
E[X\mid A]:=E[XI_A]/P(A),
$$
whenever $P(A)>0$, in which case there is nothing to prove. But one may also start with the standard measure theoretic definition of conditional expectation with respect to a $\sigma - $algebra and prove the following:

> On the probability space $\left( \Omega, \mathcal F, P\right)$, for some event $A$ such that $P(A)\in (0,1)$, let $$\mathcal G := \sigma(A)=\{A, A^C, \Omega, \emptyset\}$$ and $X$ be an integrable random variable. Then $E(X\mid \mathcal G)=E[XI_A]/P(A)$ for every $\omega \in A$. The same holds for $A$ replaced by $A^C$.

*Proof outline.*  Recall the definition of conditional expectation: $\eta:=E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ is a (any) random variable such that $EI_B\eta=EI_BX, \forall B\in\mathcal G$. One may check that 
$$
\zeta := I_AE[XI_A]/P(A)+I_{A^C}E[XI_A^C]/P(A^C)
$$
satisfies this definition. Thus, we may take $E[X\mid A]$ to mean the value of $E[X \mid \mathcal G]=\zeta$ on the set $A$ and have agreement with the definition in the first passage. I have left the details out due to the homework nature of this question.